# TDAmeritrade API for getting price history returns blank

Tags: python, api

Here's the code that i am currently using...

```
endpoint = r'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{}/pricehistory'.format('MSFT')

payload = {
    'apikey':client_id,
    'periodType':'day',
    'frequencyType':'minute',
    'frequency':'1',
    'period':'2',
    'endDate':'1556158524000',
    'startDate':'1554535854000',
    'needExtendedHoursData':'false'  
}

content = requests.get(url = endpoint, params = payload)

data = content.json()
data
```

It returns: {'candles': [], 'symbol': 'MSFT', 'empty': True}

I've tried doing it without the payload and it works fine, but i really would like to clean it up using the method now. Does anyone know the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TDAmeritrade api does not let you use `period` and `startDate/endDate` together. Remove the period from your payload and it should work. Also, make sure that your times are corresponding 6.00am.

Answer (score 0):

I was watching the same tutorial and encountered this problem. I changed the startDate and endDate and it returned an output

for instance, use:

```
'endDate':'1659697860000',
'startDate': '1659697500000',
```

you should get an output.

I'm still confused, as using other, seemingly valid, start and end dates returns blank.

I'm a noob so I can't tell what end/starts are valid, but it's clearly the main issue. pdrersin mentioned that the times should be corresponding to 6:00am, but idk what that means in this context.